# Lift and Eclipse RCP Integration

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, lift

I work on a fairly simple but large two-tier application that consists approximately 40 Eclipse RCP plugins.  We have a new use case that is taking us to the web for a very small portion of this functionality.  I'd like to prototype this using Lift.  Clearly, I'm facing a few challenges.

1. Lift + OSGi.  Can Lift get at OSGi bundles?  Can it be packaged as an OSGi bundle itself and integrated into a web container?
2. Build System.  We use the [archaic Eclipse PDE build](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html) (read: Eclipse has no build system) with Cruise Control.  Lift uses Maven.
3. Development Environment.  This one I'm not sure anyone can help me with.  I've tried to use the Scala plugin with Eclipse and it's still not ready.  There are just too many impediments to make it useful.  Saying that, I don't see this as a major issue because I can keep all the Lift code in one module, only referencing the Java code a very specific areas.

I'm wondering if anyone has tried anything similar to this and has any advice.  Note that I won't be using any of the ORM stuff in Lift because all persistence is managed in the existing plugins behind an API.  So, am I barking up the wrong tree?  Is there something else I need to be aware of?

I could revert to simply using [these instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php) but I'd really like to take Lift for a spin because Java is... well... it's Java.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [thread](http://groups.google.ru/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/6e1a31e844aa9321/c8cda6b46fe10977?hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&q=lift+osgi&pli=1) in google groups about using lift as an OSGi bundle. 
For the build system as far as I remember PDE sit's on top of ant, so you can use maven for building lift related stuff first and then call PDE's build.xml